# Submtting An animated form using jquery ajax and php to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been having problems for the past two days trying to submit a form using jquery ajax, php to mysql database. I reused a code for an animation form which I found online. The html code as follows (file name: "Slider.html"):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="form_wrapper" class="form_wrapper">
        <form class="register" style="right:-500px;backgroundcolor:grey;">
            <h3>Register</h3>
            <div class="column">
                <div>
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div>
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="r_passwordField"/>
                    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="remember">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span>Send me updates</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="registrationform" value="register"/>
                    <a href="index.html" rel="login" class="linkform">You have an account already? Log in 

here</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>      
        </form>


        <form class="login active">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" />
                <span class="error">This is an error</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password: <a href="forgot_password.html" rel="forgot_password" class="forgot 

linkform">Forgot your password?</a></label>
                <input type="password" id="l_passwordField" size="10"/>
                <span class="error">This is an error </span>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="remember"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Keep me logged in</span></div>
                <input type="submit" id="loginform" value="Login"></input>
                <a href="register.html" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account yet? 

Register here</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </form>     <form class="forgot_password">
            <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
                <div>
                    <label>Username or Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <input type="submit" id="forgortform" value="Send reminder"></input>
                    <a href="index.html" rel="login" class="linkform">Suddenly remebered? Log in here</a>
                    <a href="register.html" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account? 

Register here</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
        </form>

</div>


    <div id="graph-wrapper" class="graph-container" style="display:none">
        <h3>Standard Diviation Bell Curve<h3>
        <div class="graph-info">
                     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="visitors">Visitor</a>
             <a href="#" id="lines" class="active"><span></span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="graph-container">
                 <div id="graph-lines"></div>
             <div id="graph-bars"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery ajax code as follows (jquery script on the same file as the html code):

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

                                 //animated code and other codes omitted
          ("#registrationform").click(function(){
                    $.post("postdata.php",
    {fname:"Ibrahim",lname:"Ahmadu",email:"ibrostay@yahoo.com",uid:"ibro2stay",pwd:"ibro2stay",mean:"0.1",varience:"0.1",sdev:"0.

    1",duration:"0.1"},function(responce){

                        if(responce==0){
                                alert("There was an error updating the record");

                            }else{
                                alert("update successful");

                                }       
                            });
            });
            });
</script>
```

Below is the php code (php code file name: "postdata.php"):

```
<?php 
$fname=$_REQUEST["fname"];
$lname=$_REQUEST["lname"];
$email=$_REQUEST["email"];
$uid=$_REQUEST["uid"];
$pwd=$_REQUEST["pwd"];
$mean=$_REQUEST["mean"];
$varience=$_REQUEST["varience"];
$sdev=$_REQUEST["sdev"];
$duration=$_REQUEST["duration"];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$con)
{
    die("Error Connecting to database;"+mysql_error()); 
}


$database=mysql_select_db('mydb');
if(!$database)
{

    die("Error Connecting to database;"+mysql_error());
}


$update = mysql_query("insert into users values('$fname','$lname','$email','$uid','$pwd','$mean','$varience','$sdev','$duration')");

if(!$update)
{
    die("Update wasn't Success full"+mysql_error());
}

echo "update successfull";  

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Whenever I click the register button nothing happens. The page only refreshes back to the login form since it has class "active" as the default form, and the browser address bar changes from this url: "localhost/slider.html" to this url: "localhost/slider.html?".

I hope my question was explicit enough, because I need an urgent answer, as this is my thesis project and I am running out of options.

Answer (score 3):

> and the browser address bar changes from this url: "localhost/slider.html" to this url: >"localhost/slider.html?".

use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$("#registrationform").click(function(e){
^
|
|_______________ you forgot the $
```

then add,

```
`e.preventDefault();
```

*check javascript console and you will see all the errors. you have to eliminate one by one. For the start, check above.*

**advice**: *when you copy/paste codes, atleast try to know the structures. sometimes it wil conflict with your code and may stop running your code.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response, I did figure that out earlier anyway, but thanks for the hint.....This may sound funny to you, but I'm coding directly on notepad....Do you have links to any reliable online js code debuger?

Comment: you don't need one. Just check javacript console which is included in any modern brwoser by default or as an extension. Chrome has inbuilt, FireFox has firebug, Opera has DragonFly.... etc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Javascript has some errors and not executing hence. So, the form submit resorts to its default behavior - that is, submit to the  tag's action attribute. Since you have not specified the action attribute in the  tag, it will post the parameters to the current page.

You are getting the url *localhost/slider.html?* because of two reasons:

1. You have not specified method="post" in your . So, the form is trying to submit as GET. That is why the appended "?"
2. You do not have names for the inputs. So, the query string is empty. You need to specify name attribute for every input.

What you have to do first is to debug your Javascript. Use Firebug in Firefox or the console in Chrome or any similar tools to capture your JS errors and also examine your Ajax requests and responses.

Also, make sure that the last statement in the "click" function is a :

```
   return false;
```

to force the form to stay on the page.

Another important thing is, as @steve pointed out, add method and action attributes to your  tag. This will make sure that your script will not fail entirely on a JS disabled browser or on any such conditions.